# How did Superman know that Lois was falling to catch her in time?

Tags: dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

When Lex Luthor pushed Lois Lane from the roof in *Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice* he may not have been worried about Lois dying and taken a chance in pushing her.

But how did Superman know that Lois was falling to catch her in time?

Comment: Super-hearing + super-speed = happy Lois. He must have reacted after the push to the scream.

Comment: @Longshanks , but he was not able to hear his mother getting abducted, nor was he able to figure out where she was kept captive

Comment: Wasn't his mother abducted while she was in Kansas?Perhaps you could ask that as a separate question.

Comment: His mother was in a different city (way too far)

Answer (score 3):

### He knew, once he heard her screams

Superman can hear up to 500,000 Hz and has the best hearing, that we know of, in the DCEU according to this video:

**How Powerful is DCEU Superman**

As noted in the video Superman has the ability to hear everything up to approximately 1400 miles.

Once he heard Lois' screams, he used his 2,656,735 mph potential top flight speed ([source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1u1UkOoSMyE)) to fly from Kansas to catch her.